# iOS Many Images - maintaining good performance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iOS app where you can drag many images and rotate them. Its like a childrens app where you might build your own car using different parts (wheels, lights, etc.).  My plan is to use a UIImageview for each image and allow rotations etc.  Before I do so however, I am wondering if anyone has any thoughts on if there is a better (more efficient) approach?  Or is using UIImageViews the only option here? (It must be pre-designed images, so im not talking about creating objects with Quartz and filling them with color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES can provide you with some methods to show pics, but I think that UIImage with Core Graphics will work just fine. I've added about 100 pic (small ones, yes) to the screen and scrolled them. Smoothly on 3GS, the weakest device that I was able to use that time.
So you can bet on UIImageView, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

you can still use quartz with images. it will be a useful option when portions of you images do not change often; you'll not need to redraw all the time.

UIImageViews will become relatively slow and consume a good amount of memory if you have a lot of images/manipulations. furthermore, the layer operations (e.g. scale/rotate) don't look as good as ones you can produce using quartz. if it's a simple case, then test UIImgeViews.