# Custom UI View Change frame size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a custom UIView that draws an image in the draw rect method.  My problem is UIView wants me to initWithFrame when I allocate the object.  The frame of the view needs to be the same as the image size and width.  The problem is that I don't get that image size and width until the drawRect method of the view I am creating.  Inside the drawRect view changing the UIView's frame to the image dimensions seems to have no effect.  So what I want to do is something like this:

```
MyCustomView *myCustomView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame: CGrectMake(0,0,0,0)];
```

Then inside MyCustomView's drawRect method I want to somehow change the frame of the view to be the frame size of the image I am creating.

How do I get my desired outcome? An no, creating the image before I init my custom view and putting the size dimensions into the initWithFrame is not an option.

This is my current code in the view's drawRect method

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.imgName]];
CGSize imgSize = [image size];
CGRect newrect = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, imgSize.width, imgSize.height);
self.frame = newrect; //This does nothing!!
CGRect imgRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imgSize.width, imgSize.height);
[image drawInRect:imgRect];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the docs for setFrame it says:

> This method, in setting the frame rectangle, repositions and resizes
>   the receiver within the coordinate system of its superview. It neither
>   redisplays the receiver nor marks it as needing display. You must do
>   this yourself with display or setNeedsDisplay:.

It will not redisplay - typically after setting the frame you call setNeedsDisplay.  but, this highlights your chicken and egg problem.  setNeedsDisplay causes drawrect to fire.

Also, as Sulthan pointed out, doing something heavy like loading images in drawRect is not a good idea.  It's heavy weight and things like drawRect get called repeatedly on resize etc...

I would either create an init pattern (even though you said not an option), or create a property to set the image and have the image load at that time.

Comment: You are right. Usually I change frames before inserting the view into  another view or using animation and in both cases the view is redrawn automatically so I forget that I have to call setNeedsDisplay.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the frame from inside drawRect is... not a very good idea.
How would you imagine the system resizes something while it's currently drawing it?

Also loading the image (slow operation) from inside drawRect (can be called often) is not a very good idea.
You should load the image when you get the filename and change view frame at that time. And probably using some animation. The user won't expect the view change its size without animation.

And:

> And no, creating the image before I init my custom view and putting the size dimensions into the initWithFrame is not an option.

I can't imagine any situation when this is not an option. It's only about how you architecture your code.

Comment: From all of my reading, using drawRect to create an image in a UIView is quick and lighter weight than using UIImageViews - is that not the case? If so where can I read about that? Or do you have another suggestion? It is possible that I could have 50+ images on the screen at any given time. Also my images will most likely be scaled, rotated and flipped by the user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915320/ios-many-images-maintaining-good-performance

Comment: What is quick is to draw image in drawRect. What is not quick is the actual loading and decoding of the image data. You should do that only once. You should create UIImage somewhere before and then just draw it flipped, scaled or otherwise transformed. Don't create it over and over again. UIImageView is probably implemented exactly the same way, so your implementation is not lighter weight.

Answer (score 0):

> An no, creating the image before I init my custom view and putting the size dimensions into the initWithFrame is not an option.

I don't understand why that is not an option, but OK. You have a property on your view, `self.imgName`. When this is set (which *has* to be before the image is drawn), you should get the image, work out its size and set your frame at that point.